# Options for running a continuous webprocess

Tags: javascript, node.js, webautomation

I am interested in automation on the internet. I own a NAS server and have a website at a webhotel.

Let's start out slow. If i wanted to call a webpage a few times a day, what would my options be? On my NAS server i can write custom batch files, but I don't really want to learn how to do this, it doesn't seem too easy to get into (correct me if wrong). Are there any frameworks that can help me do this? I looked a little into Node.js, and it seems pretty good. Can i put a Node.js script on my server, and have it call a website at specified times?

So, my question is this:

what are the most widely used options, when it comes to automation on the internet?

EDIT: When I say "call a website", i mean call a webresource via a url, which would then do whatever it is instructed to do. Such as write to a database with php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually lightweight varsion of linux can be accessed on NAS servers. In this case you can install any web server on it. But considering phrases "but I don't really want to learn how to do this" and "what would my options be" I would say: Hire specialist.